# Apps Script - How to detect dialog is closed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I need to detect when a dialog is closed in Apps Script (when users click the X button in the top right of the dialog)

I tried this method but it doesn't work

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    google.script.host.close()
});
```

So how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to an HTML web-app or inside of Sheets/Docs?

Comment: Try `return false;` What browser have you tried it on?

Answer (score 1):

- Your question concerns the closure of a [custom modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs)
- This kind of dialog is defined in the html part of your script and runs client-side
- This means that to detect the closure of such a dialog, you need to implement a client-side event listener - i.e. Javascript methods
- A possibility would be to use a [window event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers) with the event [window.unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

### Sample:

> Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

> index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
 <script> 
 window.addEventListener("unload", function() {console.log("It works"); });
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> Note: The event listener in the sample will notice when the user
>   closes the dialog, however it cannot detect the difference between
>   closing by pressing the `X` and pressing the `CLOSE` button.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but on the `unload` event I want to call something on the server side like
```window.addEventListener("unload",function() {google.script.run.console.log("Window Closed");  });```

But the modal is closing without running the server call, even if I add a success handler like 
```window.addEventListener("unload", google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeFunction).console.log("Window Closed"); )};```

The modal closes instantly without calling serverside function, but will continue to run other code in the `function` block.

Comment: It's impossible to capture closing of dialog

Comment: What do you mean by your comment @IvanGussev?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to any of the sample code snippets provided in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs).

Here's an example if you're using a `Yes_No` [ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set) in an alert box -

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('YES - Confirmation received.');
  }  else if (result == ui.Button.NO) {
    // User clicked "No".
    ui.alert('NO - Confirmation received.');
  } else if (result == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the prompt.');
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't relate to my question. In my question, I stated that "when users click the X button in the top right of the dialog"

Comment: The case for "when users click the X button in the top right of the dialog"  is accounted by `if (result == ui.Button.CLOSE)`. If this is no the kind of dialog / action you meant - please specify.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @ziganotschka :) my bad on the error.

Comment: @ziganotschka: Thanks for your information. In my case, the dialog is a custom dialog https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs. I can't find any way to get the result object in order to check result == ui.Button.CLOSE. What is the solution for custom dialog?